# Inky pinky ponky game / Josephus problem

Tags: optimization, c, linked-list, circular-list

I have written below code for the famous [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), or inky pinky ponky game, or many other names. Does this looks good or is there any loophole if anyone can highlight. I shall be looking forward to optimize it now as much as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ll_core
{
    int c_ll;
    struct ll_core * next;
} node_d;

node_d * create_c_list(int ,int);
void printList(node_d *);
node_d * elimination(node_d *, int);

int main(void)
{
    node_d *c_list;
    int n_kids,num;

    printf("How many kids? ");
    scanf("%d",&n_kids);
    printf("How many no. of words? ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    node_d *first_kid=create_c_list(n_kids,num);    // create the circular list and get the pointer to first node/tail.
    printList(first_kid);

    node_d *victor=elimination(first_kid,num);      //returns pointer to the winner/last kid left
    printList(victor);
}

node_d * create_c_list(int n_k,int n_w)
{
    node_d *first=malloc(sizeof(node_d));
    int dat=1;
    first=malloc(sizeof(node_d));
    first->c_ll=dat;
    first->next=first;

    int iter=0;
    while(iter< n_k-1)
    {
        node_d * new_p=malloc(sizeof(node_d));
        new_p->next=first->next;
        first->next=new_p;                   /*We are not changing the node pointed to by tail pointer anywhere*/
        new_p->c_ll=++dat;
        iter++;
    }

    return first;
}

node_d * elimination(node_d * fix, int cntr)
{
    node_d *it=fix, *prev=fix;
    int iter;

    while(1)
    {
         for(iter=1;iter<cntr;iter++)
    it=it->next;                            /*This pointer is always on the node to be deleted. Once node is deleted, it points to the node from where
                                            from where counting is to start next.*/

    while(prev->next != it)
    prev=prev->next;                        // This always points to the node just before the one pointed to by pointer 'it'.

    //if(prev->next == it)
    prev->next=it->next;
    printf("removed : %d\n",it->c_ll);
    node_d *temp=it;
    free(temp);
    it=prev->next;

    if(it==it->next)
    break;
    }

    return it;
}

void printList(node_d *list_tail)
{
    node_d *p = list_tail->next;

    if(p->next==p)
    {
        printf("Only one element at %p: Value : %d  next : %p\n",p,p->c_ll,p->next);
     return;
    }

    while(p != list_tail)
    {
        printf("Value : %d   next : %p\n",p->c_ll,p->next);
        p=p->next;
    }

    if(p == list_tail)
    {
        printf("tail.. value : %d next : %p\n",p->c_ll,p->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is bad. It is inconsistent and makes it hard to read the code. Also adding comments at the end makes it hard to read the code. You could have placed it before the statements about which they are. Also not having braces around single statements can lead to problems later when you are editing the code and decide and add a statement but forget to add braces so you should use them even if they are optional.

Comment: You could use a double linked list to avoid going through the whole circle to find the previous node in `elimination`. This is a memory/execution speed trade-off that I find sensible especially for long lists.

Comment: If possible I would use a linked list implementation from a standard library to avoid possible bugs from pointer handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think this code is very good.

In `create_c_list`, the `first` node is allocated twice, leaking memory, and there
are no checks for allocation failure.  Parameters `n_k` and `n_w` are badly
named and the latter is not used.  The loop should be a `for` not `while`.
`new_p` could just as well be `n`, for 'node'.  Also, it is not obvious that
the 'c' in the name means 'circular' and you should add spaces around
operators ('=' etc).

In `elimination`, the function name should be a verb.  The outer `while(1)` loop is often preferred as `for (;;)` , although that is a matter of personal preference. Indefinite loops are usually best avoided anyway.
Inside this loop is a `for` loop, which should define `iter` in the loop and call it `i`.  Parameter `cntr` means nothing - it could be
'counter' of 'center'.  Give it a better name.  It derives from a value
entered by the user called `num` which gives away no secrets, and the prompt
was "How many no. of words?" - so `num` and `cntr` are the number of 'words',
but the list created by `create_c_list` makes no mention of 'words'.  It is as
if you don't want the reader to understand what it does.  The `for` loop locates the node according to the `cntr`, which takes a long time if `cntr` is zero, as the loops starts from 1.  Then you do another
loop, this time a `while` in which you find the list entry before the one
(called `it`) that you located in the `for` loop.  You could have combined the two loops.  You then delete `it` using an unnecessary temporary
variable.
And so the outer loop continues until there is only one entry in the list - that condition could have been the condition for the outer `while` loop.

In `printList` (which uses camelCase while `create_c_list` doesn't)  you don't
modify the list, so it should be passed `const`.  Parameter `list_tail` is
inaccurate - a circular list has no tail.  Call it just `list`.

Also, putting `main` last avoids the need for prototypes, all functions except
`main` should be `static` and the names of `struct ll_core` and `c_ll` would
be better as `struct node` and `value`.